# Humour/Comedy websites in German

Tags: learning, resource, joke

Are there any websites out there which offer a large repository of jokes and humour in German?

I'm looking for something similar to, for example, [www.9gag.com](http://www.9gag.com) or Comedy Central's [www.jokes.com](http://www.jokes.com).

Comment: I don't want to nag, but this question isn't really on-topic for this site. Since we have hardly any activity, I don't think anyone cares that much, but why would someone *upvote* this question?

Comment: I agree to @K.Stm. to some extent. This question is not about German or its usage. Chat would be a way better place to ask for this. - However, on-topic or not is not a reason for upvoting, respectively not.

Comment: You can delete it if you want. I only added it as a question because I noticed that resources was a common tag. I've bookmarked the dmoz page and made a note of TV show and comedian.

Comment: I think [tag:resources] should be used for questions regarding resources for anything *about* the German language, not *involving* German in one way or another. @Em1 Whether a question is on-topic or not should definitely be a criterium for upvoting. I could ask several interestings questions only touching German, but they don't belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have problems to define German humour?
Is there a specific German humour?

It is easier to give some hints to jokes and humour websites in German.

A starting point may be [DMOZ World:Deutsch:Freizeit:Humor](http://www.dmoz.org/World/Deutsch/Freizeit/Humor/). Jokes are [Witze](http://www.dmoz.org/World/Deutsch/Freizeit/Humor/Witze/)

On Youtube you can find also many German speaking comedians/joke maker...

I would recommand [Loriot](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Loriot&oq=Loriot).
[Karl Valentin](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=karl%20valentin) was also a very famous comedian in pre WWII-era.

Comment: Ahh thanks very much. Sorry maybe the title is unclear but I'm not ture how else to phrase it. Maybe I'll remove the capital 'H' in humour. I didn't mean jokes and comedic stories that can only be appreciated by people with a knowledge of German culture (a specific German humour). But rather a place where I can find jokes etc. written or spoken in the German language.

Answer (score 2):

- Im Web entstanden, und fürs Web entstanden:

  - Kurz & graphisch: [ahoi polloi](http://ahoipolloi.blogger.de/). Weniger als 1 Witz pro Tag, vielleicht 3 oder 5 pro Woche.
  - Ebenfalls graphisch: [Nicht lustig](http://nicht-lustig.de/main.html). Keine Ahnung über die Witzfrequenz.
  - Auf Hinweis @loopers: [Der Postillion](http://www.der-postillon.com/) mit Klamauk und vielen Kalauern.
- Älter als das Web

  - ist die [Titanic](http://www.titanic-magazin.de/newsticker.html), ein Satiremagazin. Einige Inhalte werden ins Web gestellt, wenige eigens fürs Web gestaltet. Das Hauptmedium ist aber noch das Magazin. Deutsche Kultur zu kennen ist oft, aber nicht immer nötig. Es gibt auch internationale Witze.

Comment: +1 für ahoipolloi.

Comment: Ahhh, ahoi polloi ist sehr gut. Danke fur deine Anwort.